# Transfer uploaded image to another website directory

Tags: php

I've a html upload form which process by Php. Following is the Upload Process code:

**Php uploading file process.**

```
if($image["name"] != "")
{
//$path = PATH . DS . "uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id;
$path = "../../uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id;
if(!is_dir($path))
    {
mkdir($path);
}
chmod($path, 0755);
//move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $path . DS . $image["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $path . DS . 
$uploadImage);//exit;               
}
```

Now I'm trying to Transfer this uploaded image to another website directory in the same time with following code:

**Another Website Directory Example:**

```
www.myanotherdomain.fr/onefolder/finalfolder/
```

**Transfer Code:**

```
// FTP access parameters
$host = 'hostname';
$usr = 'username';
$pwd = 'password';

// file to move:
$local_file = "../../uploads" . DS . "products" . DS . $id;
$ftp_path = "www.myanotherdomain.fr/onefolder/finalfolder";

// connect to FTP server (port 21)
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");

// send access parameters
ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");

// turn on passive mode transfers (some servers need this)
// ftp_pasv ($conn_id, true);

// perform file upload
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);

// check upload status:
print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
print "\n";

/*
** Chmod the file (just as example)
*/

// If you are using PHP4 then you need to use this code:
// (because the "ftp_chmod" command is just available in PHP5+)
if (!function_exists('ftp_chmod')) {
function ftp_chmod($ftp_stream, $mode, $filename){
    return ftp_site($ftp_stream, sprintf('CHMOD %o %s', $mode, $filename));
}
}

// try to chmod the new file to 666 (writeable)
if (ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0666, $ftp_path) !== false) {
print $ftp_path . " chmoded successfully to 666\n";
} else {
print "could not chmod $file\n";
}

// close the FTP stream
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't upload to my another website directory. Is there any wrong in my code or Is there any other way to upload to another website directory too.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

```
Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Prohibited file name:  
www.myanotherdomain.fr/onefolder/finalfolder/ in /home/gastrono1/www/admin/actions
/productAction.php on line 86
Cannot upload 


Warning: ftp_chmod() [function.ftp-chmod]: Could not change perms on 
www.myanotherdomain.fr/onefolder/finalfolder/: No such file or directory in 
/home/gastrono1/www/admin/actions/productAction.php on line 105
```

Comment: If you would have an ssh access to one of these server it would be easy. Do you? And if you dont this could help http://www.blogsolute.com/ftp-to-ftp-transfer-online-software/22464/

Comment: @360flowMichael what is ssh ?

Comment: Its protocol to help you manage your server remotely http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell

Comment: @360flowMichael I don't transfer the image via ftp to ftp. I just want when i upload the product picture it's also upload to my another website directory.

Comment: Ah, that changes things :) Code debugging will help i belive

Comment: Use debugger or manually check values of each line if they are what is expected.

Comment: @360flowMichael I checked all code. that's why i need your help.

Comment: `But unfortunately it doesn't upload to my another website directory.` But whats the output of your script?

Comment: It's just only upload my product picture in original directory. Not another directory.

Comment: Is this code is right ?

Comment: @360flowMichael I'm Uploading some error message.

Comment: @360flowMichael I updated my code. Please check it.

Comment: It seems that its something wrong with filename or full destination path. Try to google the warning. F.e. http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/phpstuff/329579/329579/ftp-upload+prohibited-file-name/